# Turn on boundary layer if more than one record in the map extent/ layout view?

Tags: python-2.7, arcgis

Anyone have any ideas as to how can I automate the process where if there is more than one administrative boundary area in the map extent to turn on that boundary layer for map labeling using a python script from within a map document?

For instance, if there are multiple county boundaries within the visible map extent (say the area of interest overlaps two counties) to turn on the boundary layer? I do not want to tabulate intersection on the area of interest as it does not cover the entire layout. In effect, if only one county is displayed in the map extent/layout, do not turn on the county layer. However, if it does display more than one county, turn on the county layer for display in the map extent/layout. I am trying to automate map production and am stuck on this one as I am “tabulating the intersection” of the map/layout extent, not a specific feature class.

Make sense? Thanks for any and all guidance as to how to approach this.

Using ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 Advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If discovered a way yo do this. I snagged an script that creates a polygon from the current map extent. I then performed a tabulate intersection on the boundary using this polygon. If the length of the resulting table was larger than 1, I turned the layer on.

[Create polygon from map extent script link](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/44271-Create-polygon-fc-from-map-extent)